# What is the heat rejected by the air during the cooling phase?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

We have the following transformations of air in an engine with cylinders of a  volume $V = 1,1 $ L and a diameter of 7 cm.

We have also: $\frac{V_{max}}{V_{min}} = 7,9 $

The air enters the cylinders with the pressure of 1 bar.

**From A to B**: The air is compressed in an adiabatic reversible way from point $ 1 $ to point $2$. We know that its properties are related with the formula: $pv^{k_{1}}=k_2$. At the point $B$, the pressure is $P_B$

**From B to C:** It is heated with the volume constant until the pressure reaches $P_C =75 $ bar. The intern energy increases with 145,3 kJ/Kg.

**From C to D:** The air pressure is decreased in an adiabatic reversible way until it gets its initial volume.

**From D to A:** The air is cooled with a constant volume until it gets back to its initial state.

1. What is the efficiency of the engine?
2. How many cycles per second needs to be done so that the engine would generate a power of 58,84 kW?

---

I have answered questions before these and I have a problem with these three. My thoughts:

1. The efficiency of the engine is the ratio of the sum of the works done during all the phase and the heat given. If it is correct, it is the all for all the engines?
2. The energy of one cycle is the sum of the work of the four phases. If it is so, how can I proceed to find the number of cycles needed to have the a power of 58,84 kW?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the temperature at D and the temperature at A.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. No, it is not given in the problem. I think I will use Q + W = 0 and find Q. Could you help me with the last question? Thank you.

Comment: Well, if the volume is constant, then W =0.  That means that, for DA, $$\Delta U=Q$$

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thank you. Is the efficiency of the engine is: $Eff = \frac{W_{A-B-C-D}}{Q_{B-C}}$?

Comment: That's my understanding.